# Passing labels to selectize and returning values for server functions

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I want to pass distinct labels to `selectizeInput` in Shiny.  I then want the user input from selectize to pass an encoded parameter value to a function.  I have the parameter codes and labels stored in a data frame.  So, I should be able to access the parameter field in the data frame using a logical matching statement on the labels.  However, I only seem to get the row number as output - not the actual parameter code.  Also, multiple selections are not displaying.

Please see example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

dropdown_A<-as.data.frame( cbind(labels = c("red", "white", "blue"), parameter = c(800, 72, 9048)))
dropdown_B<-as.data.frame( cbind(labels = c("green", "purple", "orange"), parameter = c("xyz","def","abc")))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      wellPanel(
        selectizeInput("A", label = p("Select a color"), choices = as.character(dropdown_A$labels), multiple = TRUE),
        selectizeInput("B", label = p("Select another color"), choices = as.character(dropdown_B$labels), multiple = TRUE))),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Value_A")),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Value_B"))),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    A<-reactive({ 
      if (is.null(input$A))
        return ("Please select a color")
      else (dropdown_A %>% filter(labels == input$A)%>% select(parameter))
    })   
    B<-reactive({ 
      if (is.null(input$B))
        return ("Please select another color")
      else (dropdown_B %>% filter(labels == input$B)%>% select(parameter))
    })  
    output$Value_A<-renderText({
      as.character(A())
    })
    output$Value_B<-renderText({
      as.character(B())
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Changing your `else` to use `[` I get the codes. E.g. `else (dropdown_B[dropdown_B$labels %in% input$B, "parameter"])`

Comment: And, changing your `parameter` to a `character` in stead of a factor works too. `dropdown_A$parameter <- as.character(dropdown_A$parameter)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the parameter codes to display, and multiple selections by either:

- changing the parameter to a character (in stead of a factor), and using `%in%` rather than `==`, or
- by using `[` rather than `%>%`.

In your code, I've changed `A()` to use the character value from `dropdown_A`, and `B()` uses `[`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

dropdown_A<-as.data.frame( cbind(labels = c("red", "white", "blue"), parameter = c(800, 72, 9048)))
dropdown_B<-as.data.frame( cbind(labels = c("green", "purple", "orange"), parameter = c("xyz","def","abc")))

dropdown_A$parameter <- as.character(dropdown_A$parameter)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
      wellPanel(
        selectizeInput("A", label = p("Select a color"), choices = as.character(dropdown_A$labels), multiple = TRUE),
        selectizeInput("B", label = p("Select another color"), choices = as.character(dropdown_B$labels), multiple = TRUE))),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Value_A")),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Value_B"))),

  server = function(input, output, session){
    A<-reactive({ 
      if (is.null(input$A))
        return ("Please select a color")
     else((dropdown_A %>% filter(labels %in% input$A) %>% select(parameter)))
    })   
    B<-reactive({ 
      if (is.null(input$B))
        return ("Please select another color")
      else (dropdown_B[dropdown_B$labels %in% input$B, "parameter"])
    })  
    output$Value_A<-renderText({
      as.character(A())
    })
    output$Value_B<-renderText({
      as.character(B())
    })
  }
)
```

Here is a screenshot of the output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think this is what you want. I changed your filter comparison to an inclusion and the way you print out your data.frames.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

dropdown_A<-as.data.frame( cbind(labels = c("red", "white", "blue"), parameter = c(800, 72, 9048)))
dropdown_B<-as.data.frame( cbind(labels = c("green", "purple", "orange"), parameter = c("xyz","def","abc")))

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      wellPanel(
        selectizeInput("A", label = p("Select a color"), choices = as.character(dropdown_A$labels), multiple = TRUE),
        selectizeInput("B", label = p("Select another color"), choices = as.character(dropdown_B$labels), multiple = TRUE))),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Value_A")),
    fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Value_B"))),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    A<-reactive({ 
      if (length(input$A)==0)
        return ("Please select a color")
      else (dropdown_A %>% filter(labels %in% input$A)%>% select(parameter))
    })   
    B<-reactive({ 
      if (length(input$B)==0)
        return ("Please select another color")
      else (dropdown_B %>% filter(labels %in% input$B)%>% select(parameter))
    })  
    output$Value_A<-renderPrint({
      print(A())
    })
    output$Value_B<-renderPrint({
      print(B())
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I like topsig's solution above because it spits out the parameters as a list and this is how I need to feed them into my function.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, I learned something too. BTW, the key was just dealing with the warnings. :)